# Sarcasm in japanese

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

ご理解頂けたはずでは?

Using go as a prefix and ending the sentence with something harsh as hasude wa? sounds unnatural to me, does anyone know how this tone can be interpreted to japanese speakers if spoken to a suprior? Rude/disrespectful/false formality/anger

Answer (score 3):

Sentence-end はずでは in isolation is not necessarily harsh; it just means "I thought ～?", and it can be safely used in polite conversations with your boss. But this sentence as a whole can be harsh if said to your superior. Superficially, the word choice is perfectly polite and respectful as keigo. Semantically, the sentence is saying something harsh; "I thought you have understood this matter (but actually you do not seem to have understood it correctly)." Of course this can sound fairly sarcastic in a situation where keigo is not necessary (e.g., to your close friend).